# Using values from `__m256i` to access an array efficiently - SIMD

Tags: c++, arrays, simd, avx2

Let's say, for example, that I have 2 variables `__m256i` called `rows` and `cols`, the values inside them are:

```
rows: 0, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2, 3, 0
cols: 1, 2, 7, 5, 7, 2, 2, 6
```

Now, these values represent the `x` and `y` positions for 8 points, so, in this case I would have these points:

```
p0: [0, 1], p1: [2, 2], p2: [7, 7], p3: [5, 5]
p4: [7, 7], p5: [2, 2], p6: [3, 2], p7: [0, 6]
```

I also have an array called `lut` that will have values of `int` type:

```
lut: [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 60, 61, 62, 63]
```

What I want to do, is to use these positions values from `rows` and `cols` variables, access the `lut` array with it and create a new `__m256i` value with the `lut` accessed values.

The way I know of how to do that would be to store `rows` and `cols` values in two `int` arrays of size 8, then read the values from `lut` array one at a time and then use `_mm256_set_epi32()` to create the new `_m256i` value.

This works, but it seems to me to be very inefficient.. So my question is if there is some way to do it faster.

Note that these values are just for a more concrete example, and `lut` doesn't need to have ordered values or size 64.

thanks!

Comment: Lookup tables in general aren't very efficient on modern processors because they always create data dependencies, so if you can find a way to replace the look-up table with some kind of arithmetic formula, even if it's a bit complicated, it can be faster. Otherwise, see the answer by chtz.

Comment: Show us your code. Than it may possible to give you an optimization hint.

Comment: Sometimes you can slice up your indices into 4-bit chunks and use them with `pshufb` to get a 16-element LUT.  (e.g. look at SSE/AVX popcount implementations like http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html.)  But when your indices aren't "separable", you'd have to do multiple shuffles with the low bytes, and blend on the high bytes, so this is O( 2^(n-4) ) work for indices with n-bit significant bits, where n>=4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a solution using an [avx2 gather instruction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=gather&techs=AVX2), like so

```
// index = (rows << 3) + cols;
const __m256i index = _mm256_add_epi32( _mm256_slli_epi32(rows, 3), cols);
// result = lut[index];
const __m256i result = _mm256_i32gather_epi32(lut, index, 4);
```

Be aware that on current CPUs gather instructions have quite huge latency, so unless you can interleave some instructions before actually using `result`, this may not be worth using.

To explain the factor of 4: The `scale` factor in

```
__m256i _mm256_i32gather_epi32 (int const* base_addr, __m256i vindex, const int scale)
```

is considered as actual byte-offset, i.e., the returned value for each index is:

```
*(const int*)((const char*) base_addr + scale*index)
```

I don't know if there are many use-cases for that behavior (perhaps this is to make it possible to access a LUT with 1byte or 2byte entries (requiring some masking afterwards)). Perhaps this was just allowed, because scaling by 4 is possible, while scaling by 1/4 or 1/2 would not be (in case someone really needed that).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted! Just one thing, I could't get why scale is 4 in this case.. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: @E.B. I added an explanation (though I'm not sure about the actual motivation for that behavior)

Comment: A decompression / decoding function might well have byte-offsets in a vector, rather than C-style unscaled indices.  I think they just decided to give you the flexibility of scaling by 1, 2, 4, or 8 since they had those 2 bits in the instruction encoding that they might as well use for the usual purpose.  Decoding a VSIB byte is pretty much the same for the decoders (and internal uop format I assume) as a regular SIB byte (used for regular non-gather indexed addressing modes like `mov eax, [rdi + rcx*4 + 1234]`).

Comment: Or in this case, it would allow the OP to compress the LUT to byte elements, at the cost of having to mask the gather result.  (And some cache-line-splits on the loads, since they still load 4B).